# What is the meaning of "0": "uint8 255"?

Tags: remix

In the console, I am getting:

> Decoded output { “0”: “uint8:  255” }

and in the return value I am getting:

> 0: 0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000ff

What the above two things mean? and is the above converting "uint8" into uint256?

Some body please guide me.

Zulfi.

Answer (score 2):

It is hex ff (at the end), left padded with 31 0x0 to make a word. It's the first 32-byte word (0).

In decimal, the value is 255.

Hope it helps.

Comment: There are two values in each case but same. Does "0" mean initial value and "255" means the final value?

Comment: It's numbering the return values. Consider a case with more than one returned value. 
`0: address: studentAccount xCA35b7d915458EF540aDe6068dFe2F44E8fa733c 1: uint256: age 1  2: uint256: income 1 3: uint256: score 1 4: uint256: attendance 1
`

Comment: My program was returning just a single value of size uint8. It was 0 initially but when i did "dec" it became 255 or hex 'ff' but its showing uint8 as a 64 bit value? I can't understand why are we numbering the values? & why 8 bit uint is represented as a 64 bit value?